# Control system block diagram reduction problem.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

From a [control system block diagram reduction](https://youtu.be/Efh_xT4Lvhg?t=433) came the following equation:

$$y = \frac{\frac{G_2G_3}{1+G_3H_2}}{1+\frac{H_3G_2}{1+H_2G_3}}$$

from which point the solution solves to this:

$$\frac{G_2G_3}{1+H_2G_3+G_2H_3}$$

Could someone explain to me what exactly is done?

I am following [this](https://youtu.be/Efh_xT4Lvhg?t=433) video to learn and the minute where the step takes place is at @ 7:13.

Comment: Multiply the top and bottom by $1+H_2G_3$.

Comment: Thanks. Don't know how I missed that. Should probably get some sleep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$y = \frac{\frac{G_2G_3}{1+G_3H_2}}{1+\frac{H_3G_2}{1+H_2G_3}}$$

$$ \Leftrightarrow y = \frac{\frac{G_2G_3}{1+G_3H_2}}{\frac{1+H_2G_3}{1+H_2G_3}+\frac{H_3G_2}{1+H_2G_3}}$$

$$ \Leftrightarrow y= \frac{\frac{G_2G_3}{1+G_3H_2}}{\frac{1+H_2G_3+G_2H_3}{1+G_3 H_2}} $$

$$ \Leftrightarrow y= \frac{ G_2G_3}{1+G_3H_2} \cdot \frac{1+G_3H_2}{1+H_2G_3+G_2H_3}$$

$$ \therefore y = \frac{G_2G_3}{1+H_2G_3+G_2H_3}$$